iPhone screen producer / manufacturer / vendor
I Like to Write an App to Check for the manufacturer details. The app itself is quite simple.Is there any variable (UIDevice or UISreen), where I can find the manufacturer info. I am wondering if there is any way, to obtain the manufacturers name or unique code by reading it out by Swift/ Xcode.
I searched quite a while on the web, but could not find any hint.
Thanks
BR
Joe

Hi there, not sure what 's missing. The info I am looking for is Cleary described: Where, if it is possible at all, can I find the the HW vendor/ manufacturer of the different components like Screen, batterie, camera etc. My hope was to find someone in this community who knows the correct parameter "path". I am puzzled to notice (again) that my questions are not answered :-(
